# Dropbox - soft link from external hard drive doesn't get recognized by Dropbox on OS X

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, dropbox, symbolic-link

I store some super large compilation of files on my external hard drive because there isn't enough space on my Macbook Pro. I would like to have them in my Dropbox as well. In this question [Uploading large folders to Dropbox from external hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/906286/uploading-large-folders-to-dropbox-from-external-hard-drive) the OP seems to have success in using soft link to back up his folders in external hard drive to Dropbox.

However it didn't work in my case: Dropbox simply seems to think those links are nonexistent and doesn't back up the contents. I suspect the reason is because my external hard drive is in `NTFS+` while my local hard drive is in `HFS+`, and I use the tool "Paragon NTFS for Mac OS X" to be able to write to the external drive.

However I think soft links are supposed to work across file systems? Is there any work around to this.

Comment: Since your question is about the file synchronization feature of Dropbox rather than the Web interface, your question is better suited to [su].

Comment: Basically the same question as [here](http://superuser.com/q/906286/50173)

Comment: @nixda Thanks. I actually am using symlink already for other folders in my Mac. However I guess the issue in my case is that my external drive is in `NTFS+` format while my OS X drive is in `HFS+` format, so Dropbox doesn't recognize the link. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can symlink the a folder in the external hard drive as a folder in your Dropbox folder.

http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/sync-other-folders

Use a symlink. To do this, use the ln command, for example:

```
ln -s /path/to/folder/that/you/want/to/sync/ ~/Dropbox/folder/name
```

Or download [SymbolicLinker](http://seiryu.home.comcast.net/~seiryu/symboliclinker.html)

Comment: Thanks. I actually am using symlink already for other folders in my Mac. However I guess the issue in my case is that my external drive is in `NTFS+` format while my OS X drive is in `HFS+` format, so Dropbox doesn't recognize the link. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Do you need to use your external with other computers (e.g. Windows)? If not, you can either re-format at HFS or Linux friendly ext2/ext3. since Mac OS X is essentially a flavor of Unix, you should able to change your UID to match both file system and use symlinks seamlessly: http://lifehacker.com/5702815/the-complete-guide-to-sharing-your-data-across-multiple-operating-systems

Comment: exFAT is a common format between Mac and Windows, you will need to use `diskpart` CLI to "show" the hidden drive in Windows so that format/letter will persist and show whenever Windows boots, otherwise you gotta use Disk Management everytime to reassign. Also, may need to "mount" the drive in macOS Disk Utility once, but from then on it should be a common drive for both computers. I'm currently trying to hold a master Dropbox copy on that shared drive